# postgres make a records chain in one table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres 9.4 and I need to do the following:

When new inserted record comes, I need to find previous records with given parameters and assign it's 'next_message' column value to newly generated record. So I want each record had reference to the next one with given filter, for example 'session_id'. So, if session_id=5, all records with seesion_id=5 should reference next one. I created a trigger that selects previous record and set this field. But it's bad and it will not work in highly loaded db table. How to do that?

That's my trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "public"."messages_compute_next_message" ()  RETURNS trigger
  VOLATILE
AS $dbvis$
DECLARE previous_session_message integer;

BEGIN
/*NEW.next_message_id=NEW.id;*/
update message set next_message_id=NEW.id where id=(select max(c.id) from message c where c.session_id=NEW.session_id and c.id<>NEW.id);
RETURN NEW;
END
$dbvis$ LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

If I post records too frequently, I get many null values in next_message_id fields. And it's logical, otherwise I have to block entire table on every insert. How to do that properly in postgres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say forget about `next_message_id`.

The way your trigger looks, it seems to me that messages are ordered by `id` within one session.

So if you need the previous message for the message with `id` 42, you can find it with

```
SELECT max(prev.id)
FROM message prev JOIN message curr
     ON prev.session_id = curr.session_id
        AND prev.id < curr.id
WHERE curr.id = 42;
```

Setting the right indexes will speed this up considerably.

I assume there already is an index on `id`; maybe a second index `ON (session_id, id)` will help.